# add additional anchors in navigation menu

Tags: navigation

I am working on this website - http://floorz.dcdev1.com/

I want this page (http://floorz.dcdev1.com/carpet/) to appear under the Services tab with the Area Rugs, Laminate Flooring etc. How do I achieve this in Wordpress? Right now there is no link pointing to the `Carpet` page.

Comment: You just need to add it under  `Appearance -> Menus` as a child element of those links.

Answer (score 0):

> ## Defining a Menu
>
> You must define a menu before you can add items to it.
>
> 1. Login to the WordPress Dashboard.
> 2. From the 'Appearance' menu on the
>      left-hand side of the Dashboard, select the 'Menus' option to bring
>      up the Menu Editor.
> 3. Select Create a new menu at the top of the page
> 4. Enter a name for your new menu in the Menu Name box.
> 5. Click the Create Menu button.
>
> ## Adding Items to a Menu
>
> You can add different link types into your menu, these are split
>   between panes left of the menu you're currently editing.
>
> 1. Locate the pane entitled Pages.
> 2. Within this pane, select the View All link to bring up a list of all the currently published Pages on your site.
> 3. Select the Pages that you want to add by clicking the checkbox next to each Page's title.
> 4. Click the Add to Menu button located at the bottom of this pane to add your selection(s) to the menu that you created in the previous
>      step.
> 5. Click the Save Menu button once you've added all the menu items you want.
>
> Your custom menu has now been saved.

Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide